# Managing media by folder

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plugin that could help me managing more precisely medias. I'd like to be able to manage folders and sub-folders.

I found out the ImageManager plugin but it's kind of outdated (http://soderlind.no/archives/2006/01/03/imagemanager-20/) so if anyone can help ;)

PS : working on WP 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give [NextGEN Gallery Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) a try. While not specifically intended for sub-folder management of media, the end result is the same, since images added to galleries are organized by folder.